# use the hidden form value in virtuemart joomla

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

i want to use the hidden form value "virtuemart_product_price" a **administrator\components\com_virtuemart\helpers\calculationh.php**
this form is added in **components\com_virtuemart\views\cart\tmpl\default.php**  ..

```
<form method="post" class="product js-recalculate" action="/ecomm/index.php/component/virtuemart/">


<div class="addtocart-bar">

        <!-- <label for="quantity229" class="quantity_box">Quantity: </label> -->
        <span class="quantity-box">
            <input type="hidden" class="quantity-input js-recalculate" name="quantity[]" value="1"/>
        </span>


        <span class="addtocart-button">
            <input type="submit" name="addtocart" class="addtocart-button" value="Pick free" title="Pick free" />               </span>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="virtuemart_product_price" value="5" />
    <input type="hidden" class="pname" value="Custom Item"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_virtuemart"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="view" value="cart"/>
    <noscript><input type="hidden" name="task" value="add"/></noscript>
    <input type="hidden" name="virtuemart_product_id[]" value="<?php echo virtuemart_product_id;?>"/>
       </form>
```

i tried to get but i can't find a solution.

Comment: It will not work VM is taking price from product_price table and apply all the rules Profit/Discount by using product id ten it saving on cart session. what are you trying achieve?

Comment: i want to set product price dynamically from product page. so i tried to set product price to $200. i tried at calculationh.php. the code runs. but the price is applied for all of the products in the cart.

Comment: Ok, First of all what calculation is used for finding $200 dynamically ? that can be applied on the admin side as a margin/discount. even its not like that you can add cart variant prices.